# How to access each dictionary individually in a list of dictionaries using Jinja2?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, werkzeug

I have a Python list of multiple dictionaries in Flask as follows (I have also used List Comprehension to access the dictionaries):

```
app = Flask(__name__)
class Item:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.__dict__ = vals

@app.route('/')
def news_page():
    news = [{ "News" : "ABC", "Link" : "http://exampleabc.com", "Date": "01/03/20" },
           { "News" : "DEF", "Link" : "http://exampledef.com", "Date": "02/03/20" },
           { "News" : "GHI", "Link" : "http://exampleghi.com", "Date": "03/03/20" }]
    return render_template('news_screen.html', news = [Item(i) for i in news])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

My HTML Template looks like this:

```
<table>
     {% for dict_item in news %}
          <div>
            <tr> {{ dict_item.News }}  </tr> <br>
            <tr> {{ dict_item.Link }}  </tr> <br>
            <tr> {{ dict_item.Date }}  </tr> 
          </div> 
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

This, unfortunately, returns all the three dictionaries (ABC, DEF, GHI), although I want only one at a time so that I can display them on different slides individually.

Current Output:

```
ABC
http://exampleabc.com
01/03/20

DEF
http://exampledef.com
02/03/20

GHI
http://exampleghi.com
03/03/20
```

How can I access each dictionary separately so that I can display only the "ABC" News, Link and Date at a time?

Expected Output:

```
ABC
http://exampleabc.com
01/03/20
```

Comment: Have you tried using yield ?

Comment: The question itself bit unclear. I can clearly see that you got expected output but you wanted to display each dict in each page?

Comment: you can access each item by its index `{{ news[0].News }}` etc? also in your view when youre returning news you can just do `news=news` instead of creating a list from a list

Comment: @Craicerjack : That was exactly what I needed, I wasn't sure on how to index it. Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to be write extra code for access each item. Just pass same as dictionary to Jinja Tempalte. here you can modified few little changes.

```
@app.route('/')
def news_page():
    news = [{ "News" : "ABC", "Link" : "http://exampleabc.com", "Date": "01/03/20" },
           { "News" : "DEF", "Link" : "http://exampledef.com", "Date": "02/03/20" },
           { "News" : "GHI", "Link" : "http://exampleghi.com", "Date": "03/03/20" }]
    return render_template('news_screen.html', news = news )
```

After all if you want to get items in Jinja Template.

```
<table>
     {% for dict_item in news %}
          <div>
            <tr> <a href="{{ dict_item.Link }}">{{ dict_item.News }}</a></tr> <br>
            <tr> {{ dict_item.Link }}  </tr> <br>
            <tr> {{ dict_item.Date }}  </tr> 
          </div> 
     {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Else if you want to single item in Jinja Template.

```
<div class="panel">
      <div class="panel-title"><a href="{{ news[0].Link }}">{{ news[0].News }}</a></div>
      <div class="panel-body">{{news[0].Date}} </div>
</div>
```